# What does xhr.open() do with a given username and password?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking at the XHR specification [here](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) and all it says is:

```
If parsedURL's host is non-null, run these substeps:
* If the username argument is not null, set the username given parsedURL and username.
* If the password argument is not null, set the password given parsedURL and password.
```

What does this mean? Where does the xhr put it in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to take into account:

- the URL credentials won't be used if either the username is `''` or the password is null
- IE doesn't transmit the 4th and 5th parameters of the open method unless the server challenges the client for credentials with a 401 HTTP status code
- [Chrome 19 dropped support for URL embedded identities](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7e356e88c48c67b29705c53b371f1871277b805c)

> What does this mean?

If the request URL—resulting from the step 5—is not null that means that it might contain an authentication section. This component is referred as `userinfo` in the [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.2.2).

> Where does the xhr [sic] put it in the URL?

scheme:[//**[user:password@]**host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]